# How to add video block in category page

Tags: php, category-products, code

I want edit layout in category list page. need to create video content in this page for each category

example
[image]

help me please. thx XD

Comment: guide me please i'm a beginner

Comment: Have you tried my solution??

Comment: please try my answer and let me know

Comment: thx for solution. it work for me ><

Comment: You are always welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the image and create a cms static block and create your design and select for particular category as shown in image. add your video image and text in stattic block and assign to particular category

[image]